# What if I want to split the string only at spaces?

Tags: actionscript-3, textfield

Not at any part (including the middle of the word) like I do with this code:

```
    var answer:TextField = new TextField();
    var textFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
    textFormat.size=15;
    textFormat.color=0x7E7E7E;
    textFormat.font="Vrinda";
    answer.defaultTextFormat=textFormat;
    answer.selectable=false;
    answer.text=currentQuestion.answers[k];
    answer.width=600;
    answer.x=54;
    answer.y=110+k*(40)+addPixels;
    answers.push(answer);
    answer.multiline=true;
    answer.wordWrap = true;
    answer.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
    answer.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, selectViaText)
    addChild(answer);
```

I'm talking about new line.

Comment: That would be what the wordWrap parameter is for.

Comment: Do you actually want to "split a String"? or to you want to "wrap some text"?

Comment: wrap, of course i'm talking about wrapping.

Comment: That code should wrap text at spaces only, try adding a width to your textfield.

Comment: this textfield is created via as3 at runtime. and yes, i am setting a width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `textfield.multiline=true;` with `wordWrap` and `autoSize`

This works fine for me, producing wrapping text at 400 width:

```
import flash.text.TextField;

var t:TextField = addChild(new TextField()) as TextField;
t.wordWrap = true;
t.width = 400;
t.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
t.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut varius eros id massa auctor tempus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Suspendisse fermentum aliquet consequat. Nulla non est massa, ut viverra nisi. Cras ligula risus, dignissim non semper vitae, cursus sit amet sem. Vivamus bibendum porta vestibulum. Etiam porttitor elit eu turpis cursus lobortis. Mauris vestibulum pulvinar varius. Maecenas non sodales erat. Praesent id augue mi, nec laoreet diam. Fusce ultrices quam varius enim ultricies nec sagittis risus laoreet. Vestibulum ullamcorper feugiat varius. ";
```

Renders as:

[image: Wrapping example]

... which is indeed wrapping only on the spaces.

Comment: weird, but this doesn't work for me. please, take a look at the code, i edited the question.

Comment: What's your input text (what is the value of one instance of currentQuestion.answers[k])? And what does your output look like - is it not wrapping at all, or is it wrapping in unexpected places? Your code looks fine so we need to check for other influences: Is it possible there are hidden chars in your text causing or preventing breaks (non-breaking spaces, or hidden carriage returns)? Are you re-setting the field width anywhere else in code? Is your text hyphenated at all (wrap will break on natural hyphens)?